# How can I influence the the source directory of an executable or library?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, cmake, compiler-options

I recently noticed something odd when compiling the following C++ program:

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

using `g++` on linux. Specifically, I compiled the program (located in `/a/directory` ) twice using the following two commands:

1. `g++ -g -o main main.cc` and
2. `g++ -g -o /a/directory/main /a/directory/main.cc`.

For each program I entered `gdb main`, typed `break main` and ran the programs. I got the following results when gdb hit the break points:

1. Breakpoint 1, `main ()` at `main.cc:1` and
2. Breakpoint 1, `main ()` at `/a/directory/main.cc:1`.

Simply put, `g++` embeds a reference to the source directory in the binary while compiling with debugging symbols. What is more, this directory is the (literal, not normalized) directory passed to the compiler (this is confirmed by examining the binaries using `strings`).

Apparently, `cmake` builds execute `g++` in such a way that the directory is absolute, at least when building out-of-source. Conversely, I encountered one `autotools` managed project in which the source directories are local ones.

There are actually [valid reasons](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=241153) to avoid using the absolute build directory, so I would like to know the following:

Can I influence the source directory that is put into a library / executable using some compiler option? How can this be done for an entire project when using cmake (like setting directories relative to the project root)?

Secondly, I would like to know if there is a convention regarding the source directory on Linux. Ideally, it would be possible to install the sources and tools like `gdb` would pick up the actual location by using something like a source `$PATH`.

Comment: 1. You seem to be already influencing the source path directory. Do you need some other way? 2. So use `$PATH` in the `makefile` or your build tool.

Comment: Well, in `cmake` I can't control the directory in which the compilation takes place. This is why I am asking. If there were a compiler flag, then I could just add that to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: You could use the `-verbose` option when running CMake to see the exact issued compiler command lines, and compare these with the ones from other build systems.

Comment: `cmake` does not use any compiler flags, it simply uses version 2. during compilation. It does not look as if `cmake` consciously influences the source directory. Presumably, the `autotools` use version 1.

Comment: @hfhc2 May be this helps a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083285/absolute-paths-against-relative-paths-in-cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake will always use absolute paths when compiling, reason is described [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#why-does-cmake-use-full-paths-or-can-i-copy-my-build-tree).

However, you can use the GCC option `-fdebug-prefix-map` to change the debugging paths that are embedded in the binary. Its documentation is located [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).

I tried this:

```sh
g++ -g -o `pwd`/main `pwd`/main.cc -fdebug-prefix-map=`pwd`=.
```

and the gdb output was: `Breakpoint 1 at 0x1129: file ./main.cc, line 1.`

For an entire project, passing `-fdebug-prefix-map=<absolute path of source root>=<source root relative to build path>` would probably work. For example, if the sources are located under `/a/directory/` and the build directory is `/a/directory/build/` then you would pass `-fdebug-prefix-map=/a/directory/=..`.

**Edit:** It was answered before: [Make gcc put relative filenames in debug information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607155/make-gcc-put-relative-filenames-in-debug-information)